# HDMI standard: Color depth = 1

Tags: hdmi

I have to transmit B&W images (about 30fps) with resolution of 1980x1080 pixels. I would like to use a HDMI link between the generating device and the imaging device (to have standard connexions and signals). Is the HDMI standard specification take into account the B&W? I mean is HDMI able to use a lower frequency transmission rate that take into account this particular signal?
A low frequency rate is required in my application since I have to transmit the signal over a length of 10m to 15m.
Is HDMI standard foreseen such signals?

Regards,

Comment: What sort of "low frequency rate"? Apparently normal HDMI works up to 15m, so if you're careful about cables it should just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a HDMI format defined for black/white images. The video section is compatible with DVI-D. This was specified to replace the analog VGA signals, which had the same bandwidth no matter whether black-and-white or colored (in fact, B/W may be argued to have more high-frequency content :-)

However, I use a 35 foot HDMI cable from my receiver to my TV, and it works; I've seen people do 75 feet by putting a HDMI amplifier in the middle.